# Как вывести в комментариях редактор текста в ленте постов под каждым постом?

Tags: wordpress

нужен вот такой редактор [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
может как -то проще решить задачу мне нужен этот редактор чтобы была возможность вставить ссылу и картинку
мне нужен этот редактор чтобы была возможность вставить ссылу и картинку
вот страница http://egocreo.webalgoritm.tmweb.ru/mikroblog/,

как вывести редактор текста
пробовал вот так ,но работает с id ,а у коментов он одинаковый если для первых коментов можно взять id записи то для последующих это не подойдет
В файле functions.php, что находится в папке с темой, создадим новую функцию:

```
function mayak_editor_comments(){
//тут будет сценарий
}
В данный скелет вставляем сценарий на основе функции wp_editor() с нужным набором аргументов. Для примера я взял следующий сценарий:

function mayak_editor_comments(){
$settings = array(
  'media_buttons'=>0,
  'textarea_name'=>'comment',
  'quicktags'=>0,
  'teeny'=>0,
  'tinymce'=> 1,
  'textarea_rows'=>10,
);
$aut = wp_editor('', 'comment', $settings);
return $aut;
}
Теперь идем в файл comments.php и ищем код вывода текстового поля:

<textarea id="comment" class="textarea" name="comment" cols="100" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea>
Вместо этой строчки вставляем код вызова нашей функции:

<?php mayak_editor_comments(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'comment_form_field_editor' );

function comment_form_field_editor( $field ) {

    global $post;

    ob_start();

    wp_editor( '', 'comment-'.get_the_ID(), array(
                'textarea_rows' => 15,
                'textarea_name' => 'comment'
    ) );

    $editor = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    $editor = str_replace( 'post_id=0', 'post_id='.get_the_ID(), $editor );

    return $editor;

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_wp_enqueue_editor_scripts');

 function load_wp_enqueue_editor_scripts() {
 
        wp_enqueue_editor();

 }
```

Функция для reinit редактора

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function init_editors() {
        
        jQuery.each( jQuery('.wp-editor-area'), function( i, editor ) {

            var editor_id = jQuery(editor).attr('id');
            
            wp.editor.remove(editor_id);
            
            wp.editor.initialize(
            editor_id,
            {
                    tinymce: {
                        wpautop: true,
                        plugins : 'charmap colorpicker compat3x directionality fullscreen hr image lists media paste tabfocus textcolor wordpress wpautoresize wpdialogs wpeditimage wpemoji wpgallery wplink wptextpattern wpview',
                        toolbar1: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | blockquote hr wp_more | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link unlink | fullscreen | wp_adv',
                        toolbar2: 'formatselect alignjustify forecolor | pastetext removeformat charmap | outdent indent | undo redo | wp_help'
                    },
                mediaButtons: true,
                }
            );
        });

    }   

    jQuery('.comment-reply-link').click(function(){
                  setTimeout(init_editors, 10);
    }); 

    init_editors(); 
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112993/discussion-on-answer-by-valerii-vasiliev------).

Comment: дописать вот это выше <? wp_enqueue_editor (), ?>
и поставить jQuery('.comment-reply-link').click(function(){setTimeout(init_editors, 10);});

Comment: скорректировал ответ

Comment: а как поправить чтобы поле комментариев не пропадала под первыми постами ,а то пропадает если нажать кнопку ответить под другими ?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос

Comment: создал его,присоединитесь пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178632/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be

Comment: если этот вопрос решен - завершите его